# How to create a route that catch all pdf file?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf, routes

I want to have my pdf files sent this way to my users :

```
public ActionResult GetPDF( string filename )
{
    return File( filename, "application/pdf", Server.HtmlEncode( filename ) );
}
```

But I don't know how to create a route that will catch all the different pdf file in my site?

Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: How do you want the urls to those PDFs look like?

Comment: www.website.com/anything/anything/filenam.pdf but it can be nested in many level of my website since the user can put a PDF in any page of the CMS.

Comment: Anyone has an idea? Is it possible?

Comment: Why not store all the PDF files in one place so they all have the same route apart from an identifier, such as filename? I don't understand why you would want to do this. Just because a file is associated with a page doesn't mean that it has can't be linked to somewhere else. A hyperlink doesn't need to be relative to the page it's on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
string FilePath = MapPath("your.pdf");
Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";
Response.AppendHeader( "content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + FilePath);
Response.WriteFile(FilePath);
Response.End();
```

EDIT:

Oups just saw it's MVC...

Try to append the header anyway before returning...

Comment: It's working, I simply added the content-disposition header in my PDFDownloadHandler like this 

public override string GetRequestedFileMimeType(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + context.Request.PhysicalPath);
        return "application/pdf";
    }

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do what I was trying to do just read this link : http://forums.iis.net/t/1162518.aspx or this one http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Range-Specific-Requests-in-ASP-NET.aspx

It's not by routing but with a Handler in IIS.

If someone has a better solution, please, let me know :)

EDIT :

It's realy not working great, you can take a look here : http://www.ville.st-augustin.qc.ca/carte-interactive click on "carte de zonage" tab and then on any adobe icon and it's not working as it should be... any help appreciated!